# HTML5 video stops when CSS animation plays

Tags: html, css, video, css-animations

I have a html video tag with autoplay:

```
<container>
    <video src="./images/grid.mp4" preload autoplay loop muted></video>
</container>
```

The autoplay actually works, but the video stops if the parent element has a CSS animation:

```
container {
    animation: RotateColor 7s ease infinite alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes RotateColor { 
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.02);
        filter: hue-rotate(130deg);
    } 
}
```

Is this intended behaviour? Can't I use CSS animations or filters on playing video?

The CSS animation *DOES* work when I use an animating GIF in the background, but I've read that an MP4 *should* have much better performance than a GIF.

Sideways related, playing this video with other html elements on top of it causes my laptop fans to spin like crazy, CPU goes to 90%... Is there a way to mitigate this? I am scaling a small video (640 * 480) up to 1440 * 900 in the background of the website. Is the scaling the problem?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/fkp8ns0g/1/

Comment: You can manipulate video with canvas

Comment: Jsfiddle works indeed.... must be something with the content on top of my video. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use preload and autoplay both, if i know correctly

**Note: The preload attribute is ignored if autoplay is present.**

Source: w3schools

Comment: I didn’t know that, but the problem is that the CSS animation stops the video.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the same set of animations as posted by you and its working fine.

I think that the `playsinline` attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-playsinline) may be required when resizing the video element and can help here if it's not working for you.